# How do i display a single alert for multiple fields being empty?

Tags: javascript, alert

I have a form with first name, last name and email, and i need to make an alert if a field is empty. I made an alert but it comes up for every field that is empty.

This is the js:`

```
document.querySelector("#book").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let inp = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
  for (let i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
    if (inp[i].value == "") {
      alert("All fields must be filled!");
    }
  }
});
```

`

The form-control class is on all the input fields.
If i leave all 3 inputs empty, the alert comes up 3 times.

Please help, my brain is stuck.

Comment: _"This is the js:"_ - what, nothing? You forgot to actually post it. (And before you do, please go read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting, if you are not familiar with how formatting code here works.)

Comment: Simplest solution: add a `break` after the `alert`. You might also have a look at [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: So use a boolean variable as a flag then. `var errors = false;` before the loop, inside you toggle it to `true` if you encounter an error, and after the loop you simply check, if that variable now contains true, you need to show your alert ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array.some` on inputs get by `querySelectorAll()` to raise only one alert if one fields is not empty

```js
document.querySelector("#book").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
  if ([...inputs].some(input => input.value === '')) {
      alert("All fields must be filled !");
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="form-control" />
<input class="form-control" />
<button id="book">validate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an array to get all errors inside a single `array` and after the loop finish then you can give the final alert.

```js
document.querySelector("#book").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let inp = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
  let errors = [];
 
  for (let i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
    if (inp[i].value == "") {
       errors.push("Error "+ i);
    }
  }

  if(errors != []){
       alert("All fields must be filled!");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a generic message, you can just display it once, and even stop the loop:

```
document.querySelector("#book").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let inp = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
  for (let i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
    if (inp[i].value == "") {
      alert("All fields must be filled!");
      break; // <-- alert was shown, nothing else to do
    }
  }
});
```

If you want to show a single message, but specific to the missing field(s), you have to collect them in the loop, and show the single message after, something like

```
document.querySelector("#book").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let inp = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
  let missing=[];
  for (let i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
    if (inp[i].value == "") {
      missing.push(inp[i].name);
    }
  }
  if(missing.length) {
    alert("Please fill the following fields too: "+missing.join());
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Us a boolean variable to remember whether any field is empty while looking at them in the loop.

```
document.querySelector("#book").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let anyEmpty = false;

  let inp = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
  for (let i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
    if (inp[i].value == "") {
      anyEmpty = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if(anyEmpty) {
    alert("All fields must be filled!");
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `FormData` object, then loop through all of the entries. If at least one of them is empty, send one alert and return out of the function.

```html
<form>
    <label for="firstName">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="first name" name="firstName" />
    <label for="lastName">last name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="last name" name="lastName" />
    <label for="email">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email" />
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    const form = document.querySelector('form');

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = [...new FormData(e.target)];

        for (const [key, val] of formData) {
            if (!val) return alert('Failed to fill all fields.');
        }

        alert('Success!');
    };

    form.addEventListener('submit', handleClick);
</script>
```